# Benchmark tests of producer - apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I make a benchmark test of producent to check, how fast producer send data to kafka broker.

There are my results: [RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK1ry.jpg)

Can someone explain me why results look like they look?
I send 100 mln messages 64B size. Why early logs are much faster? I noticed that hardly always the 3-4 logs at beggining have bigger speed. I want to maximize my speed so maybe understanding this  this can help me.

Maybe you have idea, how i can speed up this? I increased partitions number, now I test with Ack = 0. What I can do any more?

Best regards

Comment: how did you made the benchmark? can you post the relevant part?

Comment: I base on [link](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) and commands from [link](https://gist.github.com/zodvik/b86757d45a95ed194fc9d87e507c1bcc) . I have kafka broker on one core on first machine, on one core on second machine I have zookeeper, on one core on the third machine I have producent.